# How to add custom image/styled text to table cell using officegen nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using officegen to create MS-word file using nodejs. It works perfectly fine till now. 
I need to add custom images to a table cell. But i figure out any way to it. For now am just using their default example for tables.

Code:

```
var officegen = require('officegen');
var docx = officegen ( 'docx' );
var table = [
  [{
    val: "No.",
    opts: {
      cellColWidth: 4261,
      b:true,
      sz: '48',
      shd: {
        fill: "7F7F7F",
        themeFill: "text1",
        "themeFillTint": "80"
      },
      fontFamily: "Avenir Book"
    }
  },{
    val: "Title1",
    opts: {
      b:true,
      color: "A00000",
      align: "right",
      shd: {
        fill: "92CDDC",
        themeFill: "text1",
        "themeFillTint": "80"
      }
    }
  },{
    val: "Title2",
    opts: {
      align: "center",
      vAlign: "center",
      cellColWidth: 42,
      b:true,
      sz: '48',
      shd: {
        fill: "92CDDC",
        themeFill: "text1",
        "themeFillTint": "80"
      }
    }
  }],
  [1,'All grown-ups were once children','I need to add custom image here'],
  [2,'there is no harm in putting off a piece of work until another day.',''],
  [3,'But when it is a matter of baobabs, that always means a catastrophe.',''],
  [4,'watch out for the baobabs!','END'],
]

var tableStyle = {
  tableColWidth: 4261,
  tableSize: 24,
  tableColor: "ada",
  tableAlign: "left",
  tableFontFamily: "Comic Sans MS",
  borders: true
}

docx.createTable (table, tableStyle);
```

The above code able to create a custom table. But i wasn't able to add custom image or paragraph inside table cells.

I appriciate any sort of help. thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't get any solution so i forked the officegen project and extend the functionality. https://github.com/FaheemAlam/officegen.
Sorry I don't like to fork branch but i need this feature ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

For make-up the first cell in the first row
instead of

```
[1,'All grown-ups were once children','I need to add custom image here']
```

use

```
[{"val":1,"opts":{place here your desired options - same notation as heading opts}},'All grown-ups were once children','I need to add custom image here']
```

Comment: And what of custom image?